# Find eigenvalues and eigenvectors for linear operator

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, operator-theory

$A$ is a matrix of order $n$. Suppose it has pairwise distinct eigenvalues $\lambda_1,\ldots,\lambda_n$ and corresponding to them eigenvectors $v_1,\ldots,v_n$.
Find eigenvalues and eigenvectors of operator $X\mapsto A^3XA^4$, where $X\in\mathbb C^{n\times n}$

Comment: what are your thoughts and tries?

Comment: Only matrices such that $Q^T X Q$ are diagonal where $Q$ is columns of the eigenvectors of $A$? If you brute force write out the matrix multiplications, it's clear rather quickly. So I would raise the earlier question too: where are you stuck? Or is such description no good? What is your question again?